# php returning too early

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I make a call to a php file using jquery's ajax function. It goes to the file, as it should and starts executing commands.  I have multiple

```
$stmt->execute();
```

calls, which are mysqli update queries.  But only the first one will execute, and after-which it will return instead of executing the next query.  Why does it return after only 1 query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is crashing between the queries.  Unfortunately, being PHP, it will often do so silently, leaving you scratching your head wondering what's happening.  Check your error logs & if they're empty, you might need to turn up the error reporting level.

At first glance, I'd guess that your SQL is invalid, causing an exception which is unhandled.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the only question I see is: "What should I look for that might be causing this issue?"

http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

You should be looking in your PHP logs for errors letting you know why the code halted. The default location for the log is the same files as apache's error log (or IIS if you're using that)